# CD/DVD tray keeps coming out after installing ubuntu 17.04

Tags: 17.04, cd-drive

After I have installed Ubuntu 17.04, the CD-tray keeps coming out on its own. I don't even use the drive.

What might be possible reason for this?
And, how do I fix it?

Comment: Yeah it does that when you shut down the live environment... not sure if there's anything you can do about it

Comment: It simply means the installation of Ubuntu is finished, so you can remove the media, close the tray and reboot into the new system.